# Firebase Anonymous Auth Lifetime - Device specific login - Web

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm considering using Firebase Anonymous Auth, as I am looking for a device specific token solution.

If people log in anonymously. Will they stay logged in on that browser forever? Or at what point won't they be able to see their information from that browser?

I could use a cookie, but this seems way easier given how easy it would be to later upgrade people, if they ever want to use their profile on another device.

Answer (score 0):

> If people log in anonymously. Will they stay logged in on that browser forever?

No, not forever.

> Or at what point won't they be able to see their information from that browser?

The anonymous user will essentially become unusable if any of the the following happen:

- The browser local storage for the web site is cleared, or otherwise lost somehow
- The user is signed out

Comment: Do you know how it knows, how it knows who is who? Is it a cookie? Would them restarting their computer keep them logged in?

Comment: It's just a unique token stored in the browser's local storage.  There is no cookie.  The storage lasts until one of the two things I mentioned happens